# react Vite Project not open when I run "npm run dev"

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I created a new React project using Vite react but after running `npm install` and `npm run dev`, I get the error below:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327 
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename)); ^ 

Error: The specified module could not be found. 
\\?\D:\Ostad\MERN\Student\vite-project\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-ia32-msvc\rollup.win32-ia32-msvc.node at 
Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) at
Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12) at
Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)at
require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18) at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ostad\MERN\Student\vite-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48) at Module._compile
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) at Module._load
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12) { code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED' }
Node.js v20.9.0
```

[image: Error]

I previously created another React project without using Vite and everything worked fine. So, I know the issue is setting it up with Vite.

What could be the problem please?

Comment: can we see your "scripts" section in your package.json? try running `npm run dev` instead of `npm install npm run dev`

Comment: "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },

Comment: I run only ' npm run dev ' but it's error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569907/error-in-react-vite-project-due-to-rollup-dependency-module-not-found)

Comment: 1. npm install -g create-vite
2. npm create vite@latest my-NewReact-app --template react
3. cd my-NewReact-app
4. Open Project in VS Code:
->   code .

5. Then After New Windows open, Install Dependencies in Project folder using below syntax:
->   npm install
6. Start Development Server:   npm run dev

Answer (score 1):

try removing the **node_modules** folder and the **package-lock.json** file, after that, install the dependencies again **npm install**, make sure there is the dev command in the **package.json** scripts and run **npm run dev** again, this should help you

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Node version by downloading it from the official site: https://nodejs.org/en/download then I tried npm run dev and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

## Follow the steps to create a new React JS project using Vite in VS Code on a Windows system

1. Install Vite Globally (if needed):
   If you haven't installed Vite globally, use this command:
   ->      npm install -g create-vite
2. Create a Vite Project:
   Replace my-NewReact-app with your desired project name.
   --template react specifies to use the React template.
   ->      npm create vite@latest my-NewReact-app --template react
3. Navigate to Project Directory:
   ->      cd my-NewReact-app
4. Open Project in VS Code:
   ->      code .
5. Then After New Windows open, Install Dependencies in Project folder using below syntax:
   ->      npm install
6. Start Development Server:
   ->      npm run dev